# enviar multiples parametros de tipo arreglo a un metodo post con vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, formularios

Estoy desarrollando una app de encuesta, el cual cuando el usuario va a realizar la encuesta estoy trabajando con la libreria form-wizzard de vuejs para las etapas, pero en el momento que quiero saber que va seleccionando el usuario, me refiero a las respuestas, no se como ir guardando esas respuestas, el formulario es dinamico desde el backend.

El resumen de la app es se crea un formulario con multiples etapas, cada etapa tiene multiples preguntas con respectivo tipo, { multiple, unica, si o no, texto}, cuando se los muestro al usuario para que responda la encuesta necesito saber el id de la pregunta y saber su respuesta para luego mandar todo por medio del metodo post

```
<form-wizard title="Encuesta de ficha de caracterizacion" subtitle="">

        <tab-content v-for="stage in stages" :key="stage.id" :title="stage.title">

            <div class="row">
                <div v-for="question in stage.questions" class="col">

                    <div class="form-group" v-if="question.type === 'BOOLEAN'">
                        <label >{{ question.title }}</label>
                        <input  type="radio"
                                v-for="answer in question.answers"
                                :name="answers" <!-- Linea en donde no se que colocar para agregar al arreglo de respuesta -->
                                v-model="answers.id"
                                :key="answer.id" 
                                :value="answer.id">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group" v-if="question.type === 'DATE'"></div>

                    <div class="form-group" v-if="question.type === 'MULTI_CHOICE'">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group" v-if="question.type === 'NUMBER'"></div>

                    <div class="form-group" v-if="question.type === 'SCALE'"></div>

                    <div class="form-group" v-if="question.type === 'SINGLE_CHOICE'"></div>

                    <div class="form-group" v-if="question.type === 'TEXT'"></div>

                    <div class="form-group" v-if="question.type === 'TIME'"></div>

                </div>
            </div>

        </tab-content>

    </form-wizard>
```

> Script del componente

```
import { FormWizard, TabContent } from 'vue-form-wizard'

    export default {
        components: {
            FormWizard,
            TabContent
        },
        data(){
            return {
                stages: [],
                answers: []
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.getStages()
        },
        methods: {
            getStages() {
              axios.get('/api/stages')
                  .then(response => this.stages = response.data.data)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Falta informacion en tu pregunta.  Deberias agregar la declaracion del Vue y que es lo que has intentado.

Comment: Agrega lo que tienes en tu javascript :D

Comment: ya pudo agregar un poco mas de ingormacion